# GAMS if-else syntax

Tags: algorithm, gams-math

```
if (a(i,j) gt 0,
z(i,j) eq 0;
else
z(i,j) eq 1;
);

equations
kapasite_asker(i)
kapasite_silah(i,k)
talep_asker1(j)
talep_asker2(j)
talep_silah1(j)
talep_silah2(j)
atama_asker(i)
atama_silah(i)
agirlik(i,j)
risk
amac

;

kapasite_asker(i)..   sum(j,a(i,j))=L=y(i)*c(i);
kapasite_silah(i,k).. sum(j,x(i,j,k))=L=m(i,k)*f(i);
talep_asker1(j)..     sum(i,z(i,j))=E=1;
talep_asker2(j)..     sum(i,a(i,j))=E=g(j); 
talep_silah1(j)..     sum(i,e(i,j))=E=1;
talep_silah2(j)..     sum((i,k),x(i,j,k))=E=sum(k,n(j,k));
agirlik(i,j)..        sum(k,x(i,j,k)*v(k))=L=t(i,j);
risk..                sum((i,j),(z(i,j)*r(i,j)+e(i,j)*r(i,j)))=L=25*sum((i,j),z(i,j)+e(i,j));
amac..                sum(i,f(i)+y(i))=E=p;
atama_asker(i)..         sum(j,z(i,j))=L=11*y(i);
atama_silah(i)..         sum(j,e(i,j))=L=11*f(i);

 Error 143 
    A suffix is missing
Error 141 
    Symbol declared but no values have been assigned. Check for missing
       data definition, assignment, data loading or implicit assignment
       via a solve statement.
       A wild shot: You may have spurious commas in the explanatory
       text of a declaration. Check symbol reference list.
Error 149 
    Uncontrolled set entered as constant

Error  10 
    ',' expected
 Error 140
    Unknown symbol
Error  36 
    '=' or '..' or ':=' or '$=' operator expected
    rest of statement ignored

 Error 409 in 
    Unrecognizable item  skip to find a new statement
      looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
```

**I'm new to GAMS. The code I wrote gives an error. 'a' in the code is an integer variable and z is a binary variable. How can I fix it? Or how do I connect these two variables? Thanks in advance.**
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Answer (score 0):

Since a and z are both variables, the if-else statement is not good to use for their assignment. You can use big-M method and add two constraints for such a logic:

-M*z <= a <= M*(1-z) - eps, where M is a positive scalar, and eps is a sufficient small number by default.